# Used "pip3 install" to successfully installed "pytesseract", but when I try to import it at Jupyter Notebook, it failed on me

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

Once again, the "pip3 install" was successful

This is what the error message looks like:

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> <ipython-input-1-fb370059137a> in <module>
>
>        1 from PIL import Image
>
>  ----> 2 import pytesseract
>
>        3 import sys
>
>        4 from pdf2image import convert_from_path
>
>        5 import os
>
>  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract'
> ```

Comment: If this is this an `Anaconda` environment, never use pip to install packages that are available through conda. [pytesseract: conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytesseract).  Make certain you installed to the correct `env`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check which pip you are using for installation and also see where your Jupyter Notebook is reading from.

1- In the terminal (outside Jupyter), make sure that you can import the package. Note the path of your Python.

2- When in Jupyter Notebook, find your Python path with the following command and make sure they match:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

If the problem was not a PATH issue (which it seems it is!), you should figure out why it's not installed correctly.

Comment: if they don't match, how do i change?

Comment: There are quick fixes but I recommend you to take a look at conda virtual environments and jupyter lab. They handle better this path problem. Create a conda env using `conda create -n myenv`, activate it with `conda activate myenv`, do `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab` and finally run the jupyterlab via `jupyter lab`. You could access classic notebook in jupyterlab from Help > Launch Classic Notebook. Examine your path again. You should do your other installations when the conda env is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing **Pillow** package along with the pytesseract package

```
pip install pytesseract Pillow
```